# Is it possible to get a closed form expression for $E\left(\dfrac{1}{a+e^Z}\right)$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $a>0$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution

The question is in the title. So all we need to do is compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}}{a+e^x}dx$$ I tried some integration by parts tricks but could not proceed. To be clear, I am looking for a function of $a$ that is very clear and explicit.

Comment: Straightforward integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{a+e^x}dx$.

Comment: Yes but how do you compute it?

Comment: Look up Integral Table.  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Said text is over 1000 pages in length, to which section in particular do you refer?

Comment: Definite integrals of exponential.